# When is "public" needed in a class definition?

Tags: java

This question relates to where **classes** themselves (not their methods or data) need to be declared as public.

Currently I'm a Java noob, self taught with just the very basics. I'm familiar with several other languages, but in Java I've only written extremely basic programs, like with everything in the one main class (one file).

So today I decided to try something new, and put classes in separate files. What surprised me was that when I placed a class in a separate file, that this class was accessible to the main program, even if it wasn't marked "public".

For the sake of a definite example, lets say I've got **just** two files in the one folder. File "mainprog.java" containing the following:

```
class mainprog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello myHello = new hello();
        myHello.sayHello();
    }
}
```

And file "hello.java" containing the following:

```
class hello {
    void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Nothing in "hello" is specified as public, but this compiles and runs just fine with

```
javac mainprog.java
java mainprog
```

So I'm just kind of wondering where "public" really is needed for class definitions?

**EDIT to add new information**
As suggested by answers below, I tried adding a "package" statement to each file, so as to make them from different packages. As expected the access to class "hello" was then denied unless I made both the class "hello" and it's method "sayHello() public. Thanks everyone.

Comment: public classes are visible *outside the package* they are declared in

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both classes are **package-private**.  They both reside in the same folder, so both classes can see each other.

If one class were residing outside of the package, or another class from another package needed access to those, it wouldn't be available.

[Here's a reference to Oracle's visibility of methods/classes/fields.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have added in the question that I don't know what a package is, or what specifies if files are part of a package or not. So is it as simple (in this case) as if the files are all in the same **folder** then they are considered to be part of the same package (even if no packages are formally defined)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  If no packages are defined, then it's considered to be in the default package.

Comment: Thanks Makoto, that's answered my question. Yes I had googled this and found that public was required to make the class visible outside of the current package. It was just that I knew I hadn't defined any packages, so was surprised it worked without a "public" specifier. You've cleared up my misunderstanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Package definition

> A Java package is a mechanism for organizing Java classes into namespaces similar to the modules of Modula. Java packages can be stored in compressed files called JAR files, allowing classes to download faster as a group rather than one at a time. Programmers also typically use packages to organize classes belonging to the same category or providing similar functionality.
>
> A package provides a unique namespace for the types it contains.
>       Classes in the same package can access each other's package-access members.

**Use of public class.**

When you want to make the object this class from another package.

Suppose you have one class in Demo package.

```
Demo package.
  Demo.java
```

Both class are in different package.

```
Demo1 package
   Demo1.java
```

Now you want to create a object of Demo.java class in Demo1.java which are in different package then you need to define the Demo class public.

Read this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Thanks TGMCians. I haven't got up to defining packages yet. I was aware of their existence, but haven't yet looked into how they're defined or anything. It looks like I'll have to make that the next thing to learn. :)

Answer (score 1):

By default all the classes under the same package[or folder] has a access modifier 'protected'. So you can access the class without any trouble. Refer the 'Inheritance' concept and you will have a better idea of the access modifiers. Cheers !!